# How to make a multiplication and division without overflow and any loss of precision in Vyper

Tags: vyper, overflow, math, safemath

How can I calculate X * Y / Z in vyper uint256 without overflow and any loss of precision?

I want to build Vyper FullMath library functions similar to the Uniswap V3 FullMath library written in Solidity.

X * Y is definitely bigger than 2 ** 256 but the result will be in uint256 range.